# Jquery fadeIn not working and I can not find the solution to the issue

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to get the jQuery fadeIn working on my h1 element. I have checked to see if the jQuery has been activated by using an alert message, but it doesn't seem to be working on the element.

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="f1" class="banner-quote">
    <h1>"text"</h1>
</div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f1").fadeIn(1000);
});
</script>
```

Could it be something in relation to my CSS or is there something in that code which I am missing?

Comment: just to clarify the div does have its surronding opening tag, i just didnt copy and paste it correctly.

Comment: Is your '"#f1' element initially hidden using css? I.e. before the jquery fadeIn kicks in, is the element hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Set the CSS on default with `display: none` . otherwise, is not showing fadein effect

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#f1").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#f1{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f1" class="banner-quote">
  <h1>"text"</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) doesn't hide your html elements it **Displays** it.

From the [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) official [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) what it does is

> Display the matched elements by fading them to opaque.

What you are probably looking for is [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t6z8L4ct/1/).